# Is there an explicit function from the quotient space of an annulus to a torus?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, quotient-spaces

The annulus is  ${1\leq x^2+y^2\leq4}$
I would like to show that the quotient space of the annulus given by the equivalence relation $(x,y)\sim(x,y)$ and $(x,y)\sim(2x,2y)$ if $x^2+y^2=1$ is homeomorphic to the torus.
But I can't seem to find an explicit homeomorphism.

I tired to write it as $(\sin(2\pi r),\cos(2\pi r)),(\sin(2\pi \theta),\cos(2\pi \theta)) $ where $1\leq r\leq 2,\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ but that doesn't give a equivalence relation. Any ideas?

Comment: How is the torus given?

Comment: the torus $S^1xS^1$

Comment: Is there a problem with writing $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ and then mapping
$$(x,y)\ \longmapsto\ ((\cos\theta,\sin\theta),(\cos(\tfrac{2}{3}(r-1)\pi),\sin(\tfrac{2}{3}(r-1)\pi)).$$

Comment: So your torus is the set of all $(a,b,c,d)$ with $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362204/torus-and-square

Comment: You want an explicit homeomorphism. That means you have to know explicitly where your torus is. You have to know which points of ${\bf R}^3$ or ${\bf R}^4$ or whatever make up your torus.

Comment: Have you noticed that taking polar coordinates on the annulus shows that it is isomorphic to $[1,2]\times S^1$, and that your equivalence relation descends to the equivalence relation on the interval $[1,2]$ that identifies the endpoints?

Comment: what do you mean by isomorphic? homeomorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll consider $S^1$ as the unit circle in $\Bbb{R}^2$, and hence $S^1\times S^1$ as a subset of $\Bbb{R}^4$.

For every point $(x,y)$ on the annulus $A$ there are unique $r\in[1,2]$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ such that $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, and the map
$$A/\sim\ \longrightarrow\ S^1\times S^1:\ (x,y)\ \longmapsto\ \left(\left(\cos\theta,\sin\theta\right),
\left(\cos(2(r-1)\pi),\sin(2(r-1)\pi)\right)\right),$$
is a homeomorphism.

Comment: I think $r$ is in $[1,2]$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are right, thanks for noticing, it is getting a bit too late here. At least that gets rid of the fractions :)